# Adding an XML file to your XNA project

Tags: c#, xna

I'm creating an XNA game. I've made it so I can specify all the level details in an XML file which is then de-serialized and used to set up the level details.

At the moment, it's just referencing a file on my computer - my question is, how do I reference this more generically?

Adding the xml in my content folder created a multitude of complaints about schemas and such like, which made me think that likely wasn't the correct route.

Any suggestions?

I tried removing all the entries from the XNA, this gives:

Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(System.String)

EDIT:

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type = "RDrop.Level[]">
  <Item>
    (stuff)
  </Item>
  <Item>
    (stuff)   
  </Item>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

EDIT:

I've started a new windows phone project - the previous one wasn't one. I've copied everything over and added "dataTypes" ala this tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604979.aspx

Game project references -> content, MyDataTypes.
Content references -> MyDataTypes.

The XML is as is in previous edit and is contained in the content folder via Add-> Existing Item-> Level.XML.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can get more answers on this subject on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Having re-read this a couple of times I'm not seeing anything that is XNA/game specific. This is just a question about de-serialising some XML.

Comment: @Kev This is `XnaContent` - it's supposed to be built into binary data by the XNA content pipeline's `XmlImporter`. (As per Robert's answer.)

Comment: Joshua, would you like me to migrate this over to our games dev site, you might get betters eyes on this question?

Comment: Robert seems to be on the right track here - though I seem to have opened a can of worms trying to shoe horn this in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave the build action as "Compile".  One method to do what you want is the following:

Create a class that the xml is going to be describing.  Example: Level.cs

Then structure your xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XnaContent>
    <Asset Type="The_Level_class_namespace.Level">
        <Property1>Value</Property1>
        <Property2>Value</Property2>
        <Property3>Value</Property3>
        <Property4>Value</Property4>
    </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

if you want the xml to describe an array of objects you can do structure the xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XnaContent>
    <Asset Type="The_Level_class_namespace.Level[]">
        <Item>
            <Property1>Value</Property1>
            <Property2>Value</Property2>
            <Property3>Value</Property3>
            <Property4>Value</Property4>
        </Item>
    </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

From there you just need to make sure your values are in the proper format.  For example a vector2 object would be like this:

```
<Vector2Property>x_value y_value</Vector2Property>
```

Make sure that your content project references the game project or library project.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the answer.

I'm not quite sure I follow; I've got the class and the XML that describes it.

I can de-serialise it into a class (and I am and that's working fine, my levels all load) so that's not an issue.

It's the final step of being able to get it to be in my content folder I'm struggling with.

Which bit here do I add to the XML that I've got from my class to make it work?

Comment: Scrap that, I'm a numpty. It's not recognising the namespace but I'll keep playing.

Comment: It can't find the class it's supposed to be getting this from - attempting to set a reference to my game project leads to it complaining it'd create a circular reference (because the project references it's content somewhat reasonably!)

Comment: You should add a new project to the solution to hold the library of classes that your game uses.  If this is a windows phone game, make is a "Windows Phone Game Library" project.  Put the level class in that project.  Then have the content project reference the library project, the game project reference the library project and the game project reference the content project.  The library project then does not reference either project.  that will get rid of the circular reference issue

Comment: Apologies, I'm still having trouble - if you could take a look at my latest edit I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, I've marked this as the answer as I've solved the initial problem! Many thanks, can you suggest what to use instead of a streamReader?

I get:

Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(System.String)

Comment: have you looked at this?  [Loading XML Content at Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604980.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Open the properties of your XML document (right click in your content folder). You can set the Build Action to : None.

That way, the compiler won't analyse your schema, thus it won't produce any warnings.

(I'm not entirely sure about this, just my first guess)

Comment: Hrm, this appears to have the effect of it being added to the project but unable to be used (as it doesn't get put in the build folder).

If I were to add it like this - when I came to deploy it on a phone, would this be an issue...? I feel like there should be a different method but I could be talkin' crazy.

Comment: Set the copy options to "Copy if newer" or "Copy always". That will solve your problem. I don't know if Windows Phone's file system is the same as Windows, as I have never developed on this platform.